# Google analytics API optimization

Tags: php, laravel, google-analytics, laravel-5, google-analytics-api

I am working on an application that in which I need to integrate google analytics API with PHP.
Here's the link for the API documentation [Google Analytics Core Reporting API](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/v4/#choosing_which_version_of_the_analytics_reporting_api_to_use), currently I'm facing an overload issue.

At our application we need to form a graph for selected daterange. For example session count. API has option for parameters like start & end data but in response it only provides average / total of session counts / page load time. But for generating graph we do need data of each day in the given date range. e.g. 1 jan to 30th jan of 2015, for this case we have to send 30 requests for individual day & get the data for the graph with this method. Is there any possible way in which we can reduce request count or get data in date format?

We are collecting many metrics like Average page load time, Organic Sessions etc. which is making it 180-210 request on page load to google API itself & sometimes it throws an error that too much utilization of resources from google.

Comment: I probably do not understand the question correctly, but wouldn't it work to simply add the date as dimension ? That would give you the numbers broken down by day in a single request.

Comment: Actually I want datewise data. But it's giving me an average or total data of that date range. Since I want to compose a graph, I'd need data of each date.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can add the `ga:date` [dimension](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/dimsmets#view=detail&group=time&jump=ga_date). It will break out the value for each metric for every date within the date range:

### In JSON

```
{
  "reportRequests": 
  [
    {
      "dimensions": 
      [
        {
          "name": "ga:date"
        }
      ],
      "metrics": 
      [
        {
          "expression": "ga:sessions"
       },
        {
          "expression": "ga:avgpageloadtime"
        }
      ],
      "viewId": "XXXX",
      "dateRanges": 
      [
        {
          "startDate": "7daysAgo",
          "endDate": "yesterday"
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

### In PHP

```
// Create the DateRange object.
$dateRange = new Google_Service_Analyticsreporting_DateRange();
$dateRange->setStartDate("7DaysAgo");
$dateRange->setEndDate("yesterday");

// Create the Metrics objects.
$sessions = new Google_Service_Analyticsreporting_Metric();
$sessions->setExpression("ga:sessions");
$avgpageloadtime = new Google_Service_Analyticsreporting_Metric();
$avgpageloadtime->setExpression("ga:avgpageloadtime");

//Create the Dimensions object.
$date = new Google_Service_Analyticsreporting_Dimension();
$date->setName("ga:date");

// Create the ReportRequest object.
$request = new Google_Service_Analyticsreporting_ReportRequest();
$request->setViewId("XXXX");
$request->setDateRanges($dateRange);
$request->setDimensions(array($date));
$request->setMetrics(array($sessions, $avgpageloadtime));

$body = new Google_Service_Analyticsreporting_GetReportsRequest();
$body->setReportRequests( array( $request) );
return $analyticsreporting->reports->batchGet( $body );
```